# Choosing between INTEGER and TIMESTAMP data type

Tags: amazon-redshift

For the purpose of persisting date & time values, I can naturally use the `TIMESTAMP` data type in Redshift. However I am leaning towards just relying on `INTEGER` timestamps. I can as well make use of `INTEGER` instead of native `TIMESTAMP` data type, for example, I can easily convert them as `SELECT TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + intTime * INTERVAL '1 second' from table_name;`. Since I only need resolution to the second, `INTEGER` should be alright.

One advantage, `INTEGER` data type is 4 bytes and `TIMESTAMP` data type is 8 bytes, so I suppose I can save some disk space and I/O time. Secondly, I just want to keep Redshift in sync with dynamodb database as I use `Number` data type for date & time in dynamodb.

In Redshift, date & time field (intTime) is going to be part of the compound sort key and I will heavily rely on filtering, sorting and grouping based on date and time. Will there be any performance penalties if I use `INTEGER` instead of `TIMESTAMP` when it comes to sorting, filtering and grouping as `INTEGER` mostly need to be in a `EXTRACT` function considering it is going to be part of the compound sort key. Please look at the query below for reference.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(doy from TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + intTime * INTERVAL '1 second'), count(*)  AS count
FROM table_name
WHERE TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + intTime * INTERVAL '1 second' BETWEEN '2016-12-15  00:00:00' AND '2016-12-15  23:59:59'
  AND EXTRACT(dow FROM TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + intTime * INTERVAL '1 second') IN (5, 6)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(doy FROM TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + intTime * INTERVAL '1 second')
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: No there is no issue with sorting or any performance penalties over using integer, I am already has terabyte data in UTC date,integer type column, all sorting and vacuum work well.

Comment: Apart from sorting, do you also run functions like `EXTRACT(dow FROM TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + intTime * INTERVAL '1 second') IN (5, 6)` etc.?

Comment: I am using  to_date(convert_timezone('America/New_York',(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' +(date_column / 1000)* INTERVAL '1 Second ')),'YYYY-MM-DD') ,
 date_part('hour',(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + (date_column/1000) * INTERVAL '1 Second ')) in my every query to get daily and hourly data